# How to detect if iframe's source page is fully loaded into DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want an event to fire after iframe's source page is loaded into DOM to do some customization client side. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If the iframe's content is from the same origin as the containing page, you can listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` event on it:

```
theFrame.documentWindow.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // ...
});
```

(If the content isn't from the same origin, I don't think you can hook that event — but that doesn't matter, because you wouldn't be able to do the customization you've mentioned, either. :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Use `onload` event:

```
document.getElementById("iframe-id").addEventListener("load",event=>{
    //Do some stuff when iframe loaded
})
```